# Stochastic Dominance implies inequality for expected value

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, expected-value

I know this might be a trivial question, but I was unable to find an actual proof for the following yet.

Suppose $X,Y$ are random variables where $X$ dominates $Y$, i.e. $\mathbb{P}(X \geq t) \geq \mathbb{P}(Y \geq t) $ for all $t \in \mathbb{R}$. Then, $\mathbb{E}(X) \geq \mathbb{E}(Y)$.

Intuitively this makes much sense to me, and for discrete random variales the proof is quite simple, but I cannot figure out how one proofs this in the continuous case where the expected value is given by an integral.

Comment: @StubbornAtom Yes, thanks alot! Sorry for the duplicate.